# How to center object with CSS transform scale

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to implement a zoom in/out functionality, just like you would have on a document editor like google docs or any word processor application. The problem I'm having is that I cannot keep the "document" centered and also be able to scroll all of its parts into view. Here is a small demonstration of the problem: https://codepen.io/liviu_vasut/pen/dyGbwwO

```js
document.getElementById('objectToScale').style.transform = "scale(3)";
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.object {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="objectToScale" class="object">x</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does it have to be transform scale or its fine to change width/height?

Comment: It has to be transform scale, @Kalimah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You scale only some inner element inside the whole box, but expect see the whole box scaled. if you want to scale the white padding and all the inner content to stay visible (and be able to scroll to) you should add some wrapper inside with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`, and scale it, so the whole content become scaled.

Also, as @HaoWu mentioned, you should set the `transform-origin` to `0 0`.

The final product should look somewhat like this:

```js
var scaled = false;

function toggleScale() {
  var objects = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    objects[i].style.transform = scaled ? 'scale(1)' : 'scale(3)';
  }
  scaled = !scaled;
}
```

```css
    .container {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      margin: 10px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 5px;
      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
    .object {
      position: relative;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: grey;
      border-radius: 25px;
      padding: 5px;
      transform-origin: center;
      transform: scale(1);
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="toggleScale()" value="Toggle Scale" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="objectToScale" class="object">x</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, use the `transform-origin: 0 0;` and manually set the scrollbar to the center:

```js
var scaled = false;

function toggleScale() {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName('object')].forEach(e => {
    e.classList.toggle('scaled');
    e.parentElement.scrollTop = (e.parentElement.scrollHeight - e.parentElement.clientHeight) / 2;
    e.parentElement.scrollLeft = (e.parentElement.scrollWidth - e.parentElement.clientWidth) / 2;
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.object {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.scaled {
  transform: scale(3);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="toggleScale()" value="Toggle Scale" />

<div class="container">
   <div class="object">cannot see the entire object when scaled</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but that doesn't solve the problem (it's the same with my second example in the codepen). The object is not centered within the container, there is some space on the left which is missing on the right.